# Why does the chromatic polynomial for $P_4$ not output $4!$ for input $4$?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Wolfram-Alpha says that the chromatic polynomial for the path with $4$ vertices, $P_4$, is $x(x-1)^3.$ But putting $x = 4$ gives $108$, wheres the number of $4-$colorings should be $4!$, should it not? Am I misinterpreting the meaning of the chromatic polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$4!$ is the number of colourings using four colours on the *complete* graph on $4$ vertices. For the path, you have the opportunity to use the same colour on two different vertices in a number of different combinations, opening up for many more colourings. (No, you don't have to use *all* colours at your disposal, as that would, for instance, make it impossible to use $5$ colours.)

Comment: So by $4-$ coloring that means using $4$ or $3$ or $2$ colors from the set of colors?

Comment: @Airdish Or a single colour, except for this graph that's impossible. So yes, that's what it means.